# Install npm without sudo

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, sudo

I have to install npm on a computer that doesn't have root privileges, I will have a number of errors due to missing dependencies. I attach the screen. Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

From isaacs, one of the contributors of node.js:

```
   echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
    . ~/.bashrc
    mkdir ~/local
    mkdir ~/node-latest-install
    cd ~/node-latest-install
    curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
    ./configure --prefix=~/local
    make install
    curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

For more informations:
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Comment: **npm** is bundled with Node.js, it is not necessary to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Fancy Install (Unix)

There's a pretty robust install script at https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh. You can download that and run it.

Here's an example using curl:

```
curl -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```